# Rails custom action not working due to show, how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a customer action in my campaigns controller called building.

http://localhost:3000/campaigns/building

Shows error:

```
Showing .../app/views/campaigns/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

<h2><%= @campaign.name %></h2>
<p>
  Created by: <%= @campaign.user.email %> <%= time_ago_in_words(@campaign.created_at) %> ago.
</p>
<h5>Website: <%= @campaign.website %></h5>
```

My routes file:

```
resources :campaigns do
    resources :targets
  end

  get "campaigns/building" => "campaigns#building", :as => :campaigns_building
```

Controller:

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_campaign, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
  end

  def building
  end
...
```

My show.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= @campaign.name %></h2>
<p>
  Created by: <%= @campaign.user.email %> <%= time_ago_in_words(@campaign.created_at) %> ago.
</p>
<h5>Website: <%= @campaign.website %></h5>
```

How do I make it not give this error?

Comment: You make it not give this error by making `@campaign` not nil (i.e., assigning an instance of `Campaign` to your `@campaign` variable in the `show` action of your `CampaignsController`.)

Comment: what is __find_campaign__ method and whats building's view?

Comment: *I'm trying to create a customer action in my campaigns controller called building.* You mean *custom action* right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to make a custom route and unable to make it work. If so, to make it work, you should move your *custom route* above `resources` to avoid conflicts with the default *resourceful route* and correctly route to `building` action

```
get "campaigns/building" => "campaigns#building", :as => :campaigns_building
resources :campaigns do
  resources :targets
end
```

This is because Rails tries to match routes starting from the top down. You can also define it as a `collection` route on the `resources`

```
resources :campaigns do
  get "building", on: :collection
  resources :targets
end
```